# Can iMacros Automate other Firefox Extensions?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

The description on iMacros's Firefox add-on page claims that it "is extremely versatile and can be combined with other extensions such as Greasemonkey, Web Developer, Firebug, Stylish, Download Statusbar, NoScript...", although I am not sure how this interaction works.

The reason I ask is that I am trying to implement a web scraper to navigate to websites and record HTTP interactions. However, since Tamper Data already does the HTTP request/response logging I require, I'd rather use its functionality instead of having to redo it myself.

If this is not possible, I'm wondering if anyone knows a unit tester that will allow me to:

1. Open a Firefox browser & load Tamper Data
2. Navigate to specified pages
3. Click a button on Tamper Data's UI

Answer (score 0):

Imacros is limited. Imacros cant open a new Firefox browser. Imacros can click a button addons which is creating a html content. Imacros is easier than the others.

Imacros has a TAG system. It is a fast way to writing macros and easier than Jquery :)